# Is there a BUG Calatog, classifying the bugs with general descriptions?

Tags: types, catalog

Is there any work done on classifying the bugs; practically categorizing and sub-grouping them based on their their occurrence place,  side-effects, complexity and so on? With their brief descriptions included.

Any suggestion where to find or check such a resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"The bugs"? In Stack Overflow, or what? For that I guess there's meta.stackoverflow.com.

If you're after bug-tracking software in general there is of course plenty, with lots of free and commercial alternatives.

[This index](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/Configuration_Management/Bug_Tracking//) lists at least 30 packages, both free and commercial.

Answer (score 1):

Many bug softwares allow you to prioritize according to some scheme. I havent found a universal scheme, but this is the scheme i use.

there are 4 severities.

- Minor - bug is a minor annoyance.
- Medium - bug can be worked around
- Severe - bug cant be worked around, affects customer
- Catastrophic - bug basically stops functionality which is mandatory to work.

The bugs are grouped by module name , version and further prioritized by urgency.

Answer (score 0):

A bug is defined as

> the common term used to describe an error, flaw, mistake, failure, or fault in a computer program or system that produces an incorrect or unexpected result, or causes it to behave in unintended ways. Most bugs arise from mistakes and errors made by people in either a program's source code or its design, and a few are caused by compilers producing incorrect code.

In other words; Bugs cannot be categorized as they are bound to a specific program and therefore are not universally traceable. In again other words; no, there is not, as you have to say, what program you want this list for.